# Alternative to XInclude

Tags: c#, .net, xml, alternate, xinclude

As far as I know there is no support for `XInclude` in .net.

I'd like to leverage the same kind of mechanism for hierarchically organized XML configuration files. I mean I have a top-level XML config file referencing specific Xml files. My configuration is a cluster of configurations dedicated to one particular module.

How should I do it ? (Or maybe why I shouldn't do it..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is some 3rd party support for XInclude in .NET [XInclude.NET on Codeplex](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=XInclude.NET).

If you are asking because of the configuration files, they have some sort of the same functionality build-in with configSource attribute, see this [article](http://sunali.com/2008/01/23/configsource-property-dividing-configuration-files-into-pieces/) describing it.

Comment: seems the MVP.XML package has same class name (XIncludingReader) with the XInclude.net that MS ships (see below for links). Maybe they share the same code

Comment: seem they have a bit newer version, from 2007 (than the one MS downloads site ships, from 2004) of XIncludingReader with more features for the XIncludingReader, judging from notes at https://mvpxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/4894

Comment: the only other package on NuGet that has "XInclude" Tag seems to be this one: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NXKit.XInclude/

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20170821171150/http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=XInclude.NET

Answer (score 2):

I don't use .net, but you can try using entities...

```
<!DOCTYPE example [
<!ENTITY doc1 SYSTEM "doc1.xml">
<!ENTITY doc2 SYSTEM "doc2.xml">
]>
<example>
&doc1;
&doc2;
</example>
```

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx, there is a special section on why one should prefer XInclude to entities

Answer (score 1):

MS has created a library for that.

check out http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4972

should help

- there are 3ed party solutions.
- you can extend a XmlReader to read XInclude

Comment: the idea is that they provide XIncludingReader you can use instead of XmlReader or in other places in your pipeline as a wrapper

btw, the original author (tkachenko) also had an XSL transformation tool that supported XInclude (NXSLT - http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000646.html), but seems the download site is not existing anymore. I will look into adding XInclude support to my XSLTranform tool (http://zoomicon.com/tranXform) since it is made with .NET

Comment: btw, this download seems to be from 2004, whereas the Mvp.Xml (https://mvpxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=XInclude.NET) library that includes the same code is from 2007 - https://mvpxml.codeplex.com/releases/view/4894 and has some newer stuff (e.g. it says XIncludingReader now implements IXmlLineInfo interface etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my Linq to XML XInclude extention method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Linq to XML XInclude extentions
/// </summary>
public static class XIncludeExtention
{
    #region fields

    /// <summary>
    /// W3C XInclude standard
    /// Be aware of the different 2001 and 2003 standard.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly XNamespace IncludeNamespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude";

    /// <summary>
    /// Include element name
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly XName IncludeElementName = IncludeNamespace + "include";

    /// <summary>
    /// Include location attribute
    /// </summary>
    public const string IncludeLocationAttributeName = "href";

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines the maximum sub include count of 25
    /// </summary>
    public const int MaxSubIncludeCountDefault = 25;

    #endregion


    #region methods


    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces XInclude references with the target content.
    /// W3C Standard: http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xDoc">The xml doc.</param>
    /// <param name="maxSubIncludeCount">The max. allowed nested xml includes (default: 25).</param>
    public static void ReplaceXIncludes(this XDocument xDoc, int maxSubIncludeCount = MaxSubIncludeCountDefault)
    {
        ReplaceXIncludes(xDoc.Root, maxSubIncludeCount);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replaces XInclude references with the target content.
    /// W3C Standard: http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlElement">The XML element.</param>
    /// <param name="maxSubIncludeCount">The max. allowed nested xml includes (default: 25).</param>
    public static void ReplaceXIncludes(this XElement xmlElement, int maxSubIncludeCount = MaxSubIncludeCountDefault)
    {
        xmlElement.ReplaceXIncludes(1, maxSubIncludeCount);
    }

    private static void ReplaceXIncludes(this XElement xmlElement, int subIncludeCount, int maxSubIncludeCount)
    {
        var results = xmlElement.DescendantsAndSelf(IncludeElementName).ToArray<XElement>();    // must be materialized

        foreach (var includeElement in results)
        {
            var path = includeElement.Attribute(IncludeLocationAttributeName).Value;
            path = Path.GetFullPath(path);

            var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
            if (subIncludeCount <= maxSubIncludeCount)  // protect mutal endless references
            {
                // replace nested includes
                doc.Root.ReplaceXIncludes(++subIncludeCount, maxSubIncludeCount);
            }
            includeElement.ReplaceWith(doc.Root);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The code was inspired by following blog post: http://catarsa.com/Articles/Blog/Any/Any/Linq-To-Xml-XInclude?MP=pv

Further XInclude infos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302291.aspx